# Сайты, просматривающиеся с разных устройств

Tags: веб-программирование

Некоторые сайты при открытии с телефона не помещаются по горизонтали, все мелко или даже появляется прокрутка. А некоторые смотреть удобно и с телефона, и с компьютера, и с телевизора. В чем разница?

Comment: Потому что некоторые сделали для работы на всех устройствах а некоторые - нет.

Comment: Можете объяснить это более подробно?

Comment: Вам пересказать пару толстенных книжек?)  можете начать чтение по теме "адаптивная верстка"

Comment: @MoshTumuch, веб - приложения, читайте в этом направлении.

Answer (score 1):

Это называется аддаптивная вёрстка и MEDIA-запросы.
Тема очень обширная, но если вкратце - все размеры переписываются под некие фиксированные размеры экрана - отступы, размеры шрифтов, фоновые картинки, позиции элементов.
Ну например: "если экран менее 600px, то шрифт не 16px, а 14px; отступ снизу не 100px, а 80px; " и так по всему сайту.